# Can you execute a callback function instead of a whole php file?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Here is a typical example using jquery ajax to send variables to a php page for processing, where upon completion you get the returned html or json etc...

I used something in wordpress that allows for the ajax to be sent to a callback function for all the processing instead of a whole php page.

Basically I want to have all my callback functions in ajax.php and so it's more organized.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply submit an argument like the following to your PHP file:

```
   data: "name=John&location=Boston&cmd=something",
```

At the top of the PHP file, do this:

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd']=='something')
{
  yourCallbackFunction();
  die;
}
//Rest of processing goes here
?>
```

Comment: Be sure to use `$_POST` when posting ;)

Comment: ok I was wondering if there was a method similar to the one in wordpress where you could assign to an actual function. I guess I could get the same effect if I send a variable stating which function. It's just not as nice.

Comment: also, is this method above a common practice?